# How should I connect ground and neutral for my vehicle charge circuit to my panel's bus bars?

Tags: electrical

These two rows that I see connecting white lines are they both for neutral or one is for neutral and other for ground ?  Or are both rows for neutral and I need to add the ground bar on the side?

Where do  connect the neutral and the ground on this panel for my 14-50 receptacle for my electric vehicle charger?

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on the inside of the panel's door and on either the left or right side of the breaker box itself please?

Comment: This appears to be the "main" panel where ground and neutral are combined.  In subpanels they must be kept separate, but for the main panel (in most configurations) there is no such requirement.

Comment: @HotLicks Except it appears to be a sub-panel, given that there is no stove, no AC, no clothes dryer, and everything is wired with AC cable...  seems like a sub in the garage.

Comment: If they have gas and no AC, there'd be no 220 loads.

Comment: @Mazura But what house is fully wired in armoured cable?  Seems suspiciously like a garage...  And even houses with gas appliances are usually also wired at least for a stove and dryer, even if they're not used.  In Canada it's code that you have to have at least a stove outlet - I presume NEC is the same.

Comment: @J... - Anywhere where EMT isn't required (sometimes not even then) and with a panel that old. In Chicago, no one in their right mind has electric anything, even though Illinois has the best grid in the nation. Any 2-pole breaker you find here will almost certainly be an AC, a sub, or a MWBC. If it ever was code to have a 220 AC outlet under a window, I think that's long since expired.

Comment: @Mazura Fair enough.  Usually the NEC and CEC are pretty well aligned.  Here every house at least has a range circuit, by code, whether it's currently needed or not (because future owners may want to install an electric range).  For the second point, are you saying it's normal to wire a residence with armoured cable in some places in the US?  That seems a bit... ridiculous.

Comment: @J... Chicago is infamous for requiring either conduit, AC (BX), or MC even in residential. Normal NM cable is not allowed.

Comment: @KevinCathcart ...because they're allowed to build the rest of the building out of cheese?  TIL, in any case.  I guess Chicago's mayor had a house burn down at some point and now everyone needs to wire their house like a bunker?

Comment: Half the city having burnt down might have something to do with it.... That's definitely why they're all brick and not cheese.

Comment: @Mazura I'm amazed there hasn't been pressure to adopt the universal standards used everywhere else on the continent.  EMT, at least, has sensible arguments in favour, but wiring a house with BX over NM for the sake of some ancient fire just seems nuts.

Comment: That's how I feel about wiring a house with 'extension cord' and plastic boxes, where the grounding options are a wire and myself.

Comment: @Mazura I'm curious to see the data now - is Chicago actually putting out higher safety statistics for electrical injuries and fires?  I'll have to look it up.  Fair point, in any case.  I guess it could be a main panel.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Those are BOTH neutral bars.

We can tell, because the panel has what looks like 16 *spaces*.  They must provide 1 neutral for each *space* in the panel, since you are not allowed (by NEC) to double-tap neutrals on a screw.

When you count the number of non-attachment neutral lugs, I count exactly 16.  So there you go.

**They didn't give you any ground bars in this panel.**

Given that they also didn't give you any room for grounds on the neutral bar, we can discern that this panel *pre-dates* the requirement for grounds.  However, that is fine; this Square D "QO" which is an absolutely first-rate panel there is no reason to judge it for being old.

For now, it will suffice to add the EVSE neutral and ground to the neutral bar - since this is the main panel, (or wired as a main panel), grounds are allowed on the neutral bar here.   However, grab the right ground bar - you'll need to go shopping *anyway*. I bet the model listed on the panel label is still made, and fits the mounting holes already drilled and tapped into your panel chassis (bottom edge of picture, little nubs, probably similar nubs off top of picture as well).

It looks like all your wiring is either AC cable (whose shell is ground), or THHN in conduit (noting writing on some neutral wires).  That's why you don't have any grounds now.  Check your local jurisdiction to see if you are prohibited from using NM (Romex) cable.

### You should fix the MWBCs, though!

Note that you have 12 circuits, but only 9 neutrals.  That is because three of the circuits are **Multi-wire branch circuits** (MWBCs) aka shared-neutral - a red and black hot wire sharing a cable with 1 neutral that they share.   These MUST be phased a particular way to avoid overloading the neutral wire!  (opposite: 240V between the hots). They must also be "handle-tied" so they must throw together.  Both to protect maintainers and signal to the next electrician that it is a MWBC.   You can buy approved handle-ties for QO breakers. Or you can simply use a 2-pole (240V) breaker.

Note that two of your MWBCs are on "tandem" aka "Double-stuff" breakers.   MWBCs on tandems are bad news, because it's *very easy* to place them incorrectly so the neutral is overloaded.

You need to identify the red-black pairs in each cable, and place them on 2-pole or handle-tied breakers. Talk to your Square D dealer to see if they have handle-ties for those QOT tandem breakers. Otherwise move the three MWBCs to 2-pole breakers (and move any single circuits on full breakers to the tandems).

If I counted correctly, you should finish with 3 2-pole breakers taking 6 spaces, plus 3 tandems taking 3 spaces, so this won't actually take any space in your panel.

However, you should also check to make sure QOT tandem breakers *are even allowed* in this panel.  That too will be on the panel label.   If not, they will need to be converted to full-size breakers, taking up 3 more spaces (leaving 4 left).

Comment: Definitely it's AC and not THHN in conduit.  The waxed jute cladding on the wires gives it away.  This is probably a sub-panel in a garage (hence mostly MWBC for tool outlets, no stove, AC, or other normal household loads).  Probably the AC is mounted on-wall, as is the panel.  If so, it's easiest for OP to also get AC for the charger and mount on-wall also.  NM will be a headache as it would need to go out one of the back punchouts and into the wall.  Seems like OP maybe already bought NM?  Is this another time to bring up Harper's law?

Comment: @J..., maybe, maybe not.  If this garage is an outbuilding, it's very possible the big ground wire is to a ground rod.  In that case, it's a grandfathered 3-wire feeder, and can be treated like a main panel.  In that case, the correct thing to do would be to make sure that the chassis and neutral bar *are* bonded.  OTOH, if that ground wire goes back to the main panel, converting this to a proper 4-wire feed is trivial.

Comment: @NateS. Good point.  Was thinking an attached garage, but it could be an outbuilding, you're right.  I don't see a bond between the chassis and neutral bar, though (unless it's hiding somewhere).

Comment: (Harper's Law being "Buy the wire LAST" after you have done all the learning there's time to do, wire being the least returnable item in the project.)